# Поднять <li> с определенным классом выше других <li>

Tags: javascript

Как поднять в `html` структуре на первую позицию `li` с классом `current-lang` при загрузке страницы при помощи чистого `javascript`?

```html
<ul class="language-selected">
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-10 lang-item-en lang-item-first">
    <a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-uk">
    <a lang="uk" hreflang="uk" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-ru current-lang">
    <a lang="ru-RU" hreflang="ru-RU" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил кнопку для демонстрации работы.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul.language-selected');
let liCurrent = ul.querySelector('li.current-lang');
//ul.prepend(liCurrent);

document.getElementById('makeCurrentFirst').addEventListener('click', () => ul.prepend(liCurrent));
```

```html
<ul class="language-selected">
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-10 lang-item-en lang-item-first">
    <a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="#">en-GB</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-uk">
    <a lang="uk" hreflang="uk" href="#">uk</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-ru current-lang">
    <a lang="ru-RU" hreflang="ru-RU" href="#">ru-RU</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="makeCurrentFirst">
  Make it first!
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const currentLang = document.querySelector(".current-lang");
const langsList = currentLang.parentElement;

// Удаляем елемент из DOM
currentLang.remove();
// Вставляем его перед первым в списке
langsList.insertBefore(currentLang, langsList.firstChild);
```

```css
/* ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ДЕМОНСТРАЦИИ */
.current-lang {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lang-item a:after {
  content: attr(hreflang);
}
```

```html
<ul class="language-selected">
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-10 lang-item-en lang-item-first">
    <a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-uk">
    <a lang="uk" hreflang="uk" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-ru current-lang">
    <a lang="ru-RU" hreflang="ru-RU" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так:

```css
.current-lang {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="language-selected">
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-10 lang-item-en lang-item-first">
    <a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-uk">
    <a lang="uk" hreflang="uk" href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-ru current-lang">
    <a lang="ru-RU" hreflang="ru-RU" href="#">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Простите, может сразу не правильно описала вопрос. Мне надо поднять в html структуре.

Comment: А каков практический смысл? А как эта структура генерируется? Не проще ли тогда сразу при генерировании это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно перенести в начало списка с помощью [flexbox order](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order).

```css
.language-selected {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.language-selected .current-lang {
  order: -1;
}


/* ДЛЯ ДЕМОНСТРАЦИИ */

.current-lang {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lang-item a:after {
  content: attr(hreflang);
}
```

```html
<ul class="language-selected">
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-10 lang-item-en lang-item-first">
    <a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-uk">
    <a lang="uk" hreflang="uk" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-ru current-lang">
    <a lang="ru-RU" hreflang="ru-RU" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```